# c# how to deal with events for multi dynamic created buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, events, button, handler

I have created a WinForm and I added to it dynamic Buttons, how I can deal with it's events

```
public static void Notify()
{

    var line = 3;

    Form fm = new Form();
    fm.Text = "Hello!";
    fm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    fm.ShowIcon = false;
    fm.MinimizeBox = false;
    fm.MaximizeBox = false;
    fm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
    fm.TopMost = true;
    fm.ClientSize = new Size(150, 75 * line/2);
    Rectangle workingArea = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
    int left = workingArea.Width - fm.Width-5;
    int top = workingArea.Height - fm.Height-4;
    fm.Location = new Point(left, top);
    fm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

    var buttomArray = new Button[line];

    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
    {
        buttomArray[i] = new Button();
        buttomArray[i].Text = "Button " + (i + 1);
        buttomArray[i].Location = new Point(10,30*(i+1) - 16);
        buttomArray[i].Size = new Size(130,25);
        fm.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { buttomArray[i] });
    }

    fm.Show();
}
```

I want to be able to do some different things when I click on different Button (maybe I can use the "name" as an identifier?)

cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply assign the [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) handler:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var btn = new Button();
    btn.Text = "Button " + i;
    btn.Location = new Point(10, 30 * (i + 1) - 16);
    btn.Click += (sender, args) =>
    {
        // sender is the instance of the button that was clicked
        MessageBox.Show(((Button)sender).Text + " was clicked");
    };
    Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Subscribe to the Button.Click event.  Attach the data you want to use in the click-handler to the Tag-property while your are in the creation loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) 
    { 
        buttomArray[i] = new Button(); 
        buttomArray[i].Tag=i;
    .....
```

In the click handler, the sender will be the Button (you can cast to it) and the tag will contain your value.

```
Button btn=(Button)sender;
int value=(int)btn.Tag;
```

The Tag-property accepts any type. Therefore you can attach any value to it.

Comment: Thank you the Tag property will be sure handy :-)

Comment: @Data-Base: It depends of the way your code is built. Using the Tag-propety is more old-scool. If you are used to declare eventhandler-methods for every event, this is the way to go. The inline way is more elegant and efficient but not for everyone ovious. Besides of that, it can make code unreadable if it is used in an inadequate way.